# JavaScript и DOM

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dom

Есть кнопка с id = "enterbatton" с свойсвом disabled:"true"  (пишу на рельсах).

Так же на странице есть чекбокс с id = "c1", и с опр. фукнцией onclick="Check(this)"

Вопрос, почему функция Check не хочет менять свойство disabled на true, или как это реализовать по другому?

```
<script>
function Check(element){
  if (element.checked)
    document.getElementById('enterbatton').disabled = 'false';
  ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: надо как минимум onchange использовать, click срабатывает **до** смены состояния чекбокса

Comment: результат тот же ( не робит

Comment: ну конечно, у вас что написано ? **строка** а надо **boolean**

Comment: jsfiddle.net/EURZL/2/

Comment: так тоже не хочет, делал даже через явный false (без ковычек) не робит, на каком-то форуме прочел, мол надо для .erb шаблона так экранировать, но в любом случае и так и сяк не хочет -_-

Comment: ну у меня же работает... и даже [так](jsfiddle.net/EURZL/3/)

убедитесь что id уникально

Comment: действительно, изменил имя и все заработало, но странно, у меня на странице больше нигде enterbatton не использовалось, только в CSS если.
В любом случае, спасибо! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так надо писать:

```
function Check(e){
    document.getElementById('enterbatton').disabled = !this.checked;
}
document.getElementById('checkme').addEventListener('change',Check);
```

про время срабатывания click я кстати наврал :) но все равно лучше использовать change - универсальнее, т.к. работает и для radio и для select :)